# Unable to Generate Key Hash of Facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I have tried many ways to generate a key hash.  I generated 4 different type of hashes but none of them are running, and I am still getting an error.

```
error: invalid android_key parameter. the key does not match any allowed key Configure your app key hashes at
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the Key Hash can´t be generated with the debug keystore.

> When you build in release mode you use your own private key to sign
>   your application. If you don't have a private key, you can use the
>   Keytool utility to create one for you.

More info:

**[Android Signing your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)**

**[Obtain a suitable private key](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert)**

**Update:**

check this thread:

**[invalid android_key parameter](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/issues/22)**

> Fixed!!!! create your own keystore:
>   http://circlecube.com/2013/02/keystore-for-android-app-development/

Comment: I am working in Debug Mode and using debug.keystore to generate key-hash for facebook integration but that one keyhash is not working i also tried $ jarsigner on unsigned .apk but i am getting this warning "This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated."

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved my problem after lot of search **i found keyhash in logcat**.